# How to read a recordset multiple times?

Tags: c#

I have stored an ADO recordset in a DataTable. I have iterated to its end. In the same code, I want to reiterate it, but it gives me an error -

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position -1.
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
```

I looked here - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-vba-recordset-objects/
But it does not give me an exact method to move the "row pointer" back to the 1st row.

How do I do this ?

Comment: Looks like you're tying to `.get_Item(-1)`

Comment: Post your code! We're not mind readers!

Comment: Don't use ADO.  Instead, use `DbConnection` and friends, or, better yet, Entity Framework.

Comment: Old school ADO used to have a MoveFirst method. Can you intellisense anything similar?

Comment: @SLaks - Actually, the code and the full story is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780858/looping-a-datatable-twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Recordset.MoveFirst() method. However, this will only work if the recordset was opened to support backward cursor movement.

Here's a link with more information:
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I need to loop over a recordset stored in a datatable and not the recordset itself.

Comment: Then what's the problem? Just do a foreach on the rows of the datatable, it doesn't keep track of a cursor so there's no need to reset a datatable.